# CartoDB Torque: show severity by size of marker?

Tags: carto, cartocss, torque

I have a dataset containing the cost of damage caused by individual floods over the past 100 years.
I'd like to use TORQUE to display these events on a map over time, with their severity shown by the size of the marker. ie lesser cost has a smaller marker size, greater cost has larger size.

Is there a torque aggregation function which will allow me to do this?

Here is the style I have so far, but the events still show up as one size...

```
/** torque visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:1024;
-torque-animation-duration:30;
-torque-time-attribute:"date";
-torque-aggregation-function:"count(cartodb_id)";
-torque-resolution:4;
-torque-data-aggregation:cumulative;
}

#cdd_cost_1{
marker-fill-opacity: 0.9;
marker-line-color: #FFF;
marker-line-width: 1.5;
marker-line-opacity: 1;
marker-placement: point;
marker-multi-policy: largest;
marker-type: ellipse;
marker-fill: #FF5C00;
marker-allow-overlap: true;
marker-clip: false;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 956350000] {
marker-width: 25.0;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 47368494] {
marker-width: 23.3;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 21000000] {
marker-width: 21.7;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 14523061] {
marker-width: 20.0;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 8300000] {
marker-width: 18.3;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 5738341] {
marker-width: 16.7;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 4029790] {
marker-width: 15.0;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 2828222] {
marker-width: 13.3;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 1668590] {
marker-width: 11.7;
}
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 572824] {
marker-width: 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own torque-aggregation-function by playing a bit with maths. Let's say that your column is named `floods`. Then you could do:

`-torque-aggregation-function:"round(avg(floods))";`

Please, take into account that the `value`variable of Torque is bounded by 255, so if your maximum values exceed this value (which seems that it does according to your filters) you'd need to customize a little bit more your function.

`-torque-aggregation-function:"round(avg((floods-min)/(max-min))*255)";`

Substituting min by the minimum value of floods and max by its maximum you'll get your data normalized within the range 0-255.

Then, the maximum filter of your CartoCSS should be:

```
#cdd_cost_1 [ value <= 255] {
marker-width: 25.0;
}

...
```

If this is not good enough for your use case, just let me know. I also recommend you to take a look at [this blogpost](http://andrewxhill.com/blog/2015/04/17/torque-unknown/) about Torque by Andrew Hill.

Comment: Will this take a while to generate tiles? Trying this and it seems to be hanging...

Comment: If you're doing the normalization to 255 in CartoCSS, I'd strongly recommend taking it out to SQL: just generate select/generate a new column in the table which is normalized with SQL. This might help, but without knowing the details it's hard to say... I'd recommend to take a look at the developer tools in your browser (specially network requests, to see if you find any error)

Comment: Thanks - I just posted a gist to do it w/ pandas before bringing into carto - https://gist.github.com/nygeog/03e806283c1923fb39ff538477155060